# how in unix enter folder with whitespace in name

Tags: unix, shell

as in topic. How I can do that?

Answer (score 13):

Either escape spaces or use quotes:

```
cd some\ folder
cd "some folder"
cd 'some folder'
```

The difference between the second and the third variant is that the second one can interpolate environment variables (so you better use single quotes if the filename contains $ signs).

Comment: Also `cd some?folder` (if a single space or tab and unique) or `cd some*folder` if unique.